# How to check if user likes a post on facebook with the graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I simply want to check if a user has liked a post with facebook graph api.

I tried the following query but it does not work:

```
me/likes/{post_id}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, reading the docs...

Comment: I have done that of course, and the document only refers to pages not posts

Comment: Sure, `/me/likes` is about Page, and that's documented. But it's nowhere documented that you can use `/me/likes/{post_id}`. It's also documented how to get the likes on objects, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes#read

Comment: With {post-id}/likes I can see all likes, but I want know if I like this post. I have to go through all likes and search for user (me)?

Comment: Yes, as @luschn said

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do using fb graph api 2.4

Adding field likes.summary(true) to your request should do.

Answer (score 1):

It´s not that easy, you would have to go through all likes and search for the user. This is the API call: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes#read

Comment: Hmm, that's sounds too bad. The docs say "The object must not have already been liked by the user" but not reveal how to check :|